# ngModel $formatters not being invoked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm wondering why my $parsers are being invoked but my $formatters are not being invoked.  I modified the plunker in [Custom Control Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) to include $parsers and $formatters.  It looks like my $parsers are being invoked but my $formatters are not being invoked.  Am I using $parsers and/or $formatters incorrectly?  Here is my modified plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/o1EM05AtDGw2OMDwv9dR.

```
angular.module('customControl', ['ngSanitize']).
  directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
        };

        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
          console.log("parsing");
          return viewValue + "_extra_model_stuff";
        });

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
          console.log("never formats : (");
          return modelValue + "_formatted_view_stuff";
        });

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$apply(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
  }]);
```

After a closer inspection of angular.js, it looks like ctrl refers to an ngModelController.  I expected it to refer to the ngModelController I was appending formatters to.  However, it ctrl.$formatters is an empty array, so this must be a different ngModelController.  I don't understand why.

```
$scope.$watch(function ngModelWatch() {
  var modelValue = ngModelGet();

  // if scope model value and ngModel value are out of sync
  // TODO(perf): why not move this to the action fn?
  if (modelValue !== ctrl.$modelValue) {
    ctrl.$modelValue = modelValue;

    var formatters = ctrl.$formatters,
        idx = formatters.length;

    var viewValue = modelValue;
    while(idx--) {
      viewValue = formatters[idx](viewValue);
    }
    if (ctrl.$viewValue !== viewValue) {
      ctrl.$viewValue = ctrl.$$lastCommittedViewValue = viewValue;
      ctrl.$render();

      ctrl.$$runValidators(undefined, modelValue, viewValue, noop);
    }
  }

  return modelValue;
});
```

Comment: The formatter **is** called in your Plunker.

Comment: @zeroflagL Do you see `never formats : ("` being logged?  I don't.  I'm using Chrome 37.0.2062.124.

Comment: Yes I do, whenever I change the text in the textarea.

Comment: @zeroflagL ok I was only editing the div rendered by the directive.  I guess I don't understand when $parser and $formatter are invoked.  I've read the angular docs, but I must be missing something because I'm not understanding when/why $formatters are invoked.  Would you mind explaining when and why $formatters are invoked for this example specifically?  Thanks!

Comment: A formatter is called when the model changes and has to be rendered. A parser is called when the UI representation changes and the model has to be updated. When you edit the `contenteditable` you change the UI representation, therefore the parser is called and the model gets updated. When you edit the textarea, then at first the same happens. But the `contenteditable` still shows the old model value. So the formatter has to be called to show the new one.

Comment: Ok, this is very helpful and beginning to make sense.  Can you explain to me why the textarea is not a UI represenation?  I assert that it's not a UI representation because the $parser isn't invoked when I edit the textarea.  I'm confused because I would have thought any DOM element linked to the model is a UI representation...which seems incorrect now.

Comment: The parser is invoked, but its own one, not yours.

Comment: Ok, that make sense.  And similarly $formatters for the textarea are invoked when I edit the contenteditable, just not mine?

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

As noted above:

> A formatter is called when the model changes and has to be rendered. A parser is called when the UI representation changes and the model has to be updated. When you edit the contenteditable you change the UI representation, therefore the parser is called and the model gets updated. When you edit the textarea, then at first the same happens. But the contenteditable still shows the old model value. So the formatter has to be called to show the new one.
>
> The parser is invoked, but its own one, not yours.